# Cleanup old multi-line strings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have some old code I'm tasked with updating and a lot of it has multi-line strings that are coded as follows:

```
string value = "SELECT * " +
               "FROM test_tbl " +
               "WHERE test_field = 123 ";
```

I am trying to get it to look like the code below:

```
string value = @"SELECT *
                 FROM test_tbl
                 WHERE test_field = 123 ";
```

I know this is a different string with added white space and newlines in it but this is more about readability in the code than what the string ends up looking like in the value variable.  Does anyone know of any tools or hotkeys or anything else that can help with automatically converting the code?

Comment: i dont think any tool will do it automatically since it is vastly different than the input.

Comment: Those strings should be being tidied up *out* of the code; resources file perhaps. Does look like a fairly easy find/replace job though; write some code to do it?

Comment: If you want to add enough spaces for indentation for readability, this is difficult to do. A simple replacement can be directly used to find and replace. It is recommended that you go to the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) to find out if there is any plug-in you want. You can also suggest this feature (problem on the DC forum).